# Specifying a range of files using regex

Tags: regex

I have a huge amount of files (in the hundreds of thousands) that all have the same format of name.
The filename format is:
    [prefix][number]suffix]
where the [prefix] and [suffix] of all the files is the same, and just the number part changes. The number part is something like 0004732
So the filenames are:
    [prefix]004732[suffix]
    [prefix]004733[suffix]
    [prefix]004734[suffix]
    etc.

I need to move a range of about 100,000 files (with consecutive numbers) to another directory, and I was wondering if it is possible to do this with a regular expression.

Comment: how moving files is possible only through regex?

Comment: `find` supports regexes. e.g. `find . -type f -name "prefix1[0-5][0-9]suffix\.txt"` for files 100-159.

Comment: If you're on Windows, Directory Opus ([features here](http://www.dearopus.com)) is the Rolls Royce of file managers. You can do that and much much more. I can't function without it.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). It's a bit difficult to specify number ranges using regex because it works on text, not numbers, but it can be done something like this (for files 1-100):

```
prefix[0-1][0-9][0-9]suffix
prefix[0-1]\d\dsuffix    #this also works in PERL regex
```

More complicated numbers get trickier. For 0-211:

```
prefix([0-1][0-9][0-9]|20[0-9]|21[0-1])suffix
```

Comment: Just a note: your regex won't match numbers from 0-99. Something like `([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9]|21[01])` should work, though. Shortened version: `(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|20\d|21[01])`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), and do the following. If you're on Mac OS X or Linux, just open a terminal. You'll need to do the following:

```
ls PREFIX* | sed 's/PREFIX\(0[0-9]\)SUFFIX/mv & tmp\/PREFIX\1SUFFIX/' | sh
```

**What is this doing?**

1. Lists all files starting with the specified prefix
2. Pipes this list to sed, which uses a regex pattern to match only files that fall within the range you specify
3. Create a new string using the move command
4. Pipes the move command string to the shell (sh) and executes it

You can **tweak the regex  to match your number range** by looking at the following:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no regex (to handle complex cases), but you can use loop easily:

The following code runs in linux. I ran simnilar code on Windows using CygWin and it works as well. Maybe there is similar way to do in Windows.

If the two numbers are with the same digits;

Example: from

> [prefix]000012345[suffix]

to

> [prefix]000056789[suffix]

:

```
for (( i=12345; i<56789; i++)); do mv "[prefix]0000$i[suffix]" /newDirectoryPath done
```

Otherwise you can do with multiple (usually two or three) commands;

Example: from

> [prefix]000012345[suffix]

to

> [prefix]003456789[suffix]

:

```
for (( i=12345; i<99999; i++)); do mv "[prefix]0000$i[suffix]" /newDirectoryPath done
for (( i=100000; i<999999; i++)); do mv "[prefix]000$i[suffix]" /newDirectoryPath done
for (( i=1000000; i<3456789; i++)); do mv "[prefix]00$i[suffix]" /newDirectoryPath done
```